# custom java package doesn't work

Tags: java, package

I am trying to create a custom package to put some of my classes, but when I try to import it into one of my programs, it says it cant be found.

This is the file I am trying to compile but it is saying the package cannot be found

```
import project_euler.Fibonacci;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(fib.getTerm(10));
    }
}
```

This is the Fibonacci class

```
package project_euler;
public class Fibonacci {
    public int getTerm(int n) {
        if (n < 0 || n > 46) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return (n > 1) ? getTerm(n-1) + getTerm(n-2) : n;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the errors I get when I try to compile

```
test.java:1: error: package project_euler does not exist
import project_euler.Fibonacci;
                ^
test.java:6: error: cannot access Fibonacci
            Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();
            ^
bad source file: C:\Users\dhout_000\Documents\Project Euler\project_euler\Fibonacci.java
file does not contain class Fibonacci
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
2 errors
```

And my directory set up is

```
> My Documents
    > Project Euler
        - test.java
        > project_euler
            - Fibonacci.class
            - Fibonacci.java
```

I just cant seem to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Why are you having your `.java` file in the package folder? Move it outside. And re-compile it.

Comment: Which directory are you running the compiler from? You should either be running it from `C:\Users\dhout_000\Documents\Project Euler` or setting the class path accordingly. It seems to me you are running it from somewhere else so the compiler is misunderstanding your package structure (which is not really that great to begin with, but that's another question).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set.

Compile and run your code from the base directory of the package hierarchy.

```
C:\My Documents\Project Euler> javac project_euler\Fibonacci\*.java

C:\My Documents\Project Euler> java project_euler.Fibonacci.test
```

You can also explicitly specify the classpath using the `-cp` option for the `javac` and `java` commands. Make sure that the base directory of the package hierarchy (`C:\My Documents\Project Euler`) is included. You could do this by specifying `.` (the current directory) when you're in `C:\My Documents\Project Euler`:

```
C:\My Documents\Project Euler> javac -cp . project_euler\Fibonacci\*.java

C:\My Documents\Project Euler> java -cp . project_euler.Fibonacci.test
```

Note: According to the common Java naming conventions, you shouldn't use underscores in names (package, class, method names), package names should be lower-case and class names should start with a capital letter. Rename the package to `projecteuler.fibonacci` (you'll need to rename the folders too, ofcourse), and rename the class `test` to `Test`.

Comment: If you look at the source code in question, you will see that the class `test` is in default package and class `Fibonacci` is in `project_euler` package. Therefore his directory structure **as shown in the question** is correct and agrees with his source code (in fact I've just tried it and it works fine). The problem is somewhere else (or what is posted in the question doesn't reflect exactly what is really on his machine).

Comment: There is no `Fibonacci` package, this is the name of the class, so there is no need for that folder to exist.

Comment: @ivantod You're right, I didn't look carefully enough. Edited my answer.